# Width с текстом

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Нужно подвинуть текст на правую сторону но когда задаешь ширину тексту он не двигается. Как можно решить проблему?

```css
#about {
    background: url(./img/xxx) no-repeat
    background-size: cover 50%;
}

#about-main {
    width: 400px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<section id="about">
        <div class="container"> 
            <div id="about-main">
                <h2>About</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы хотите сам текст поместить на правую сторону - Вы можете просто использовать `text-align: right` или же `align-items: flex-end;` в совокупности с `flex-direction: column;`:

```css
    #about {
        background: url(./img/xxx) no-repeat;
        background-size: cover 50%;
    }
    #about-main {
        width: 400px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-items: flex-end;
    }
```

```html
<section id="about">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="about-main">
            <h2>About</h2>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Если же Вы хотите перенести весь блок направо, то эти же параметры Вы можете использовать для блока `container`, так как есть ограничение ширины дочернего блока в нём.

```css
    #about {
        background: url(./img/xxx) no-repeat;
        background-size: cover 50%;
    }
    .container{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-items: flex-end;
        align-self: flex-end;
    }

    #about-main {
        width: 400px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-items: flex-end;
        align-self: flex-end;
    }
```

```html
<section id="about">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="about-main">
            <h2>About</h2>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```